# How to access the same object from multiple classes in Java

Tags: java, object, reference

I've been looking for the answer to this problem all day.

I have a value class that holds a variety of values as long as the program is running.

I create a new Value object in class A, and store an int value. 
Class A also has a printMoney() method.

```
public class A {
Value value = new Value(); 
value.setMoney(100);

public void printMoney {
System.out.println(value.getMoney);
}
```

In class B, I want to be able to call printMoney() from class A, so logically I do the following:

```
public class B {
A a = new A();

a.printMoney();
}
```

This does, however, return '0' as a value instead of '100'.

I understand that by creating an A object, I automatically create a new value object, which has its default money value. So, basically my question is; how do I solve this?

Comment: What is `value.getMoney`?  That's not a method call, and you haven't shown the code for your `Value` class.  I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: Concur..the line value.setMoney(100); is outside a method and in the class header.  Does this even compile?

Answer (score 5):

Make the object static. `static Value value = new Value();`

- `static` variables are shared across all the objects
- So the change made in `static` variable will be reflected for all the objects of class.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get that value in A you have to assign the value in A construtor, like

```
public class A {
  Value value = new Value();

  public A() {
     this.value.setMoney(100);
  }
```

otherwise, you can make the value static

Comment: I chose to make it static. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should receive the instance that creates the object B and save it then you would be able to call it
like so:

```
public class A {
    B b = new B(this);
}

public class B {
    A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    private someMethod () {
        a.printMoney();
    }
}
```